# How to reset opacity for individual tags inside a div after setting in for the whole div tag?

Tags: html, css, w3.css

I turned on w3-opacity in the div but I want it only in the background. I want the links and address to display normally.

Is there anyway to do this using only W3.CSS? if not, whats the other way? (only using html & CSS)

Thanks! (New to html and CSS, Excuse me if there any mistakes)

```
<footer> 
<div class="w3-black w3-margin-0 w3-padding-0 w3-opacity">
<nav class="w3-navbar w3-text-orange w3-opacity-off">
  <a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
  <a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a>
  <a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a>
  <a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
        </nav>
    <address class="w3-opacity-off"> bla bla bla</address>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: try in your css `.w3-opacity * { opacity: 1; }`

Comment: or `nav { opacity: 1; }`

Comment: Running an opacity rule on a container affects all elements within. 
<div style="opacity: 0;"><p style="opacity: 1;">Hello World</p></div> will render text with an opacity of 0.

Comment: I want my background to be have opacity. I just need to turn it off for the links and address. I tried:           
' <nav style="opacity: 1;" ' does not work the w3-opacity still affects everything.

Comment: Advise you just change the opacity on the background property itself, not the container holding said background.